# Are these fuel injectors leaking? How to fix?

Tags: fuel-injectors

please advise me if these 2 fuel injectors are leaking? If so, how to fix it?
My car is Toyota Matrix 2010 (103,000km).
(photos below)
Thanks.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the picture it is difficult to say if the leak is gasoline or just something else. Firstly clean that place where it is dirty. Then drive your vehicle normally. Re-check the same place. If you smell gasoline after inspecting the leaking fluid then you can replace the O-ring and the Grommet for all the fuel injectors. This what I have said is only if the leak is from the fuel injectors.

Comment: I'm with @Warg on the smell test, if you can't get your nose into the area easily (or safely) use a short piece of tube.